# I need to populate my gridview after I select a checkbox from checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview, checkboxlist

I need to populate my gridview after I select a checkbox from checkboxlist. I'm trying to use a loop, I also need to hide the gridview if the user unchecks the checkbox. Im useing a sql statement to pull the data. The sql should pull whatever data is associated with the checked box
    'Shows Books from selected Category
    Protected Sub chkbListControl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkListControl.SelectedIndexChanged

```
    Dim sqlChecked As String = "select * " _
                              & "from Books, Categories " _
                              & "where Categories.CategoryCode=Books.CategoryCode " _
                              & "order by Title;"

    Dim sqlUnChecked As String = "select * from Books where Categories.CategoryCode=Books.CategoryCode;"

    Dim selectedIndex As Integer = chkListControl.SelectedIndex
    Dim i As Integer

    If (selectedIndex <> -1) Then

        For i = 0 To chkListControl.Items.Count - 1

            If chkListControl.Items(i).Selected Then

                gvwBookList.DataSource = ReturnTable(sqlChecked)
                gvwBookList.DataBind()

            Else

                gvwBookList.DataSource = ReturnTable(sqlUnChecked)
                gvwBookList.DataBind()
                gvwBookList.Visible = False

            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your sqlchecked like this

```
 dim selectedcategories as string=""
  If (selectedIndex <> -1) Then

    For i = 0 To chkListControl.Items.Count - 1

        If chkListControl.Items(i).Selected Then

         if selectedcategories="" then
            selectedcategories=chkListControl.Items(i).value
         else
            selectedcategories &="," & chkListControl.Items(i).value
         end if

        End If
    Next
End If

 dim strSQL as string=""
             if selectedcategories.trim<>"" then
                    strSQL = "select * " _
                          & "from Books, Categories " _
                          & "where Categories.CategoryCode=Books.CategoryCode and                     Categories.CategoryCode in (" & selectedcategories &  ")" _
                          & "order by Title;"
   else
strSQL="select * from Books where Categories.CategoryCode=Books.CategoryCode;"

   end if

            gvwBookList.DataSource = ReturnTable(strSQL)
            gvwBookList.DataBind()
```

You can modify above code according to your requirement.